Можно ли использовать подчёркивания и минусы при именования классов в HTML
Увидел в видеоролике вот такую систему именования классов. Допустимо ли её использовать и вообще часто её юзают? Смущает вот этот конкретный момент с использованием имён классов: "header__center" "center-header"
Вот часть кода:
<div class="header__center center-header">
<h1 class="center-header__title">...<span class="center-header__title-desc">...</span></h1>
<div class="center-header__desc desc-header"> 
    <p class="desc-header__text">...</p>
    <p class="desc-header__text">...</p>
</div>
<a class="center-header__link link" href="#">...</a>
</div>


Это именование по методологии БЭМ.

Технически — можно, морально-этически — сами для себя решайте

Это типа удобно, если вы стили пишете в scss. Вам будет удобно писать стили типа - .center-header {&__title{} &__desc{} &__text{} &__link()} - получается из-за того, что вы обратились к элементу class="center-header__link" через &__link - вам не нужен в нём по сути дополнительный класс link.

Короче Бэм - это фигня полная, но почему-то её уважают и поэтому мне пришлось к ней привыкать.

Если бы я писал подобную вёрстку, я бы такие названия дал


<header class="header">
  <div class="header__center">
    <h1 class="header__title">
      ...
      <span class="header__title-desc">...</span>
    </h1>
    <div class="header__desc">
      <p class="header__desc-text">...</p>
      <p class="header__desc-text">...</p>
    </div>
    <a class="header__link link" href="#">...</a>
  </div>
</header>



